# Java: What is the difference between sorter and comparator in SWT TableViewer

Tags: java, swt, tablesorter, comparator

I want to make a table sortable for at least a few columns of the table, not just one.
I found a tutorial from voguela that uses viewerComparator extended class, and on other sites I found a viewerSorter extended class...

What is the difference ?
which ones is used for what situation ??

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go the official documentation, you will find that it is recommended to use ViewerComparator instead of ViewerSorter as it is deprecated. It is mentioned [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ViewerSorter.html)

Quoting from the docs:

> It is recommended to use ViewerComparator instead.

and

> Deprecated. as of 3.3 Use ViewerComparator.getComparator()